# INPUT element - how to give it a label in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, file-io

I want to customize the label for a file selector button in a page. It is not part of a FORM.

But the INPUT / LABEL elements behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome. They both show the HTML similarly. However in Chrome, clicking on "Select File" launches file selector but does nothing in Firefox. I am unsure what is wrong with it.

```
<input type="file" accept="csv" fileread="selectedFile" id="filenameselector" style="display:none">
<label class="btn btn-small btn-info" for="filenameselector">Select File</label>
```

Tracking events in firefox firebug shows the input element is getting the click but doing nothing.

```
click clientX=49, clientY=20 » input#filenameselector
DOMActivate  » input#filenameselector
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9rCQD/

Will greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `name="filenameselector"` to the input

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 25.0.1 (Win 7): file selection widget is launched. Tested both with the jsfiddle and with a page containing nothing but the code in the question. Please provide more information.

Comment: @Jukka Thanks. It is difficult to add an image for a pop-up that does not materialize!! I suspect it might be the Firefox version since everyone in my circle did not have this issue and I was on Firefox 21. I upgraded to v 25 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

See comments for two approaches to resolve what was apparently a Firefox bug